# Problem concatenating Python list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two lists, one with just one element, by doing this:

```
print([6].append([1,1,0,0,0]))
```

However, Python returns `None`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the + operator

```
>>> [6] + [1,1,0,0,0]
[6, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

What you were attempting to do, is append a list onto another list, which would result in

```
>>> [6].append([1,1,0,0,0])
[6, [1,1,0,0,0]]
```

Why you are seeing `None` returned, is because `.append` is destructive, modifying the original list, and returning `None`. It does not return the list that you're appending to. So your list *is* being modified, but you're printing the output of the function `.append`.

Answer (score 5):

For list concatenation you have two options:

```
newlist = list1 + list2

list1.extend(list2)
```

Comment: The latter modifies the list, the former creates a new one. That's a significant difference in several cases.

Answer (score 2):

use a list first (unless you really do not want to use your data in future )

```
>>> a=[6]
>>> a.append([1,1,0,0,0])
>>> a
[6, [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

another way is to use `extend()` instead of `append()`

```
>>> a=[6]
>>> a.extend([1,1,0,0,0])
>>> a
[6, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I like the mention of extend as alternative to summing, but I downvoted this answer because the result of extend is not the same as append, although in your answer you pretend like it is a different way to get the same result...

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [6]
l2 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
l1.extend(l2)
print l1
[6, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```