# Duplicating Array Python

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to duplicate an array inside the array to account for a duplicated separate array. The data I have is for thousands of numbers but for simplification, this is what I'm looking for:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,6,5,7,3]

new_a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
new_b = [2,6,5,7,3,2,6,5,7,3]

#array b
magnitude = data[:,1]

# phaseresult_i is array a

for t in range(len(time)):
    floor = math.floor((time[t]-time[0])/(bestperiod))
    phase_i = ((time[t]-time[0])/(bestperiod))-floor
    phaseresult_i.append(phase_i)

newphaseresult_i = phaseresult_i +phaseresult_i
newmagnitude = magnitude + magnitude
```

Above is what I have exactly in my code, and the length of the first array doubles but the length of the second array does not.

Comment: `to account for a duplicated separate array` What does that *mean*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem concatenating Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203238/problem-concatenating-python-list)

Comment: @jpp Duplicate both arrays so they match the original array values according to the index

Comment: Your edit make the post not be in accordance with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) standards

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `+` operator:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,6,5,7,3]

new_a = a + a
new_b = b + b
```

Comment: For my "a" the array duplicated, but for my "b" the array did not.

Comment: What has in `b` after doing this?

Comment: so I have len(a) = 1325, len(a_new)=2650, len(b)=1325, len(b_new)=1325. I've edited my original post to show what my a and b arrays are

Comment: Please, double check your code. It's a prety straight forward operation. `a` and `b` are list of integers as in your example, right?

Comment: I added a+a and b+b. Please see above.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it lazily with an [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) assuming that you wanted to repeat the concatenation more than once (but it still works if you set `n=2` for a single repeat).

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def ncycles(iterable, n):
    "Returns the sequence elements n times"
    return chain.from_iterable(repeat(tuple(iterable), n))

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ncycles(a, 3)
```

Then either call `list()` on `b` or iterate through it. For large arrays this will be more efficient, and it's a bit more convenient than using `+` concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the + operator:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,6,5,7,3]
new_a = a+a 
new_b = b+b 

print(new_a) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(new_b) #[2, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the old array to itself.

```
new_a = a + a
new_b = b + b
```

Answer (score 0):

The + operator will work if you are looking to create a new variable.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,6,5,7,3]

new_a = a + a
new_b = b + b
```

Alternatively if you wish to just change the list in place you could use .extend

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,6,5,7,3]

a.extend(a)
b.extend(b)
```